# Determine whether each pair is $f(n) = O(g(n), f(n) = \Omega(g(n)), or f(n) = \Theta(g(n)).$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

For the pair of functions, find whether it's $f(n) = O(g(n), f(n) = \Omega(g(n)), or f(n) = \Theta(g(n)):$

$a) f(n) = 12^n , g(n) = 7^n$

$b) f(n) = log_9(n^4), g(n) = log_9(n^5)$

I understand that:

$f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ if $C$ and $n_0$, $f(n) \leq C * g(n)$ $\forall n>n_o$

$f(n)$ is $\Omega(g(n))$ if $C$ and $n_0$, $f(n) \geq C * g(n)$ $\forall n>n_o$

$f(n)$ is $\Theta g(n))$ iff $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ and $f(n)$ is $\Omega(g(n))$

but how do I determine which one is which? Am I inputting some value for n? By looking at some you can tell already what it is but how would I prove it? I saw some people using limits? Do I put $f(n)/g(n)$ and then figure it out that way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's start with the easiest observation. $7^n < 12^n$ for all natural numbers. Can you see what values of $C$ and $n_0$ I'm using to show $g$ is $O(f)?

Comment: I see in a) that $f(n)$ $\geq$ $g(n)$ for all natural numbers and therefore $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$ but what would I do after that?

Comment: Yes, $f = \Omega(g)$. This is equivalent to $g = O(f)$ (this isn't hard to verify, and since you seem quite new to asymptotic notation I suggest you give it a go). If it is the case that $f = O(g)$ then you would say that $f = \Theta(g)$. We will show $f \not = O(g)$. Suppose $\exists C>0$ and $n_0$ such that $f(n) \leq C g(n)$ for all $n>n_0$. That is for $n>n_0$ we have $12^n < C 7^n \implies \left( \frac{12}{7} \right)^n< C$, however since $\frac{12}{7}>1$ you can make  $\left( \frac{12}{7} \right)^n$ arbitrarily large (such that LHS is larger than $C$ and $n>n_0$) this is a contradiction

Comment: The last sentence is exactly what I was not understanding. Thank you.

Comment: I think Ian gives you a sufficient hint for the second question. Using his hint think how the functions look compared to each other. Does one "grow" away from the other as n goes to infinity (this is basically what asymptomatic is about)? After asking yourself this, think of suitable $C$, the $n_0$ should be quite easy to think of

Comment: It seems that in this case, they both grow at relatively the same rate as it approaches infinity. The only difference is $5log_9(n)$ stays slightly above $4log_9(n)$ as it approaches infinity. Would this mean that their growth is equal then? Or is it $\Omega$ since $f(n)$ stays slightly above $(g(n))$?

Comment: Your intuition is spot on! They grow at the same rate. You're right that $f(n)$ stays slightly above $g(n)$ for every positive integer $n$, so $g=O(f)$ (when you notice this, you are using $C=n_0=1$). Is $f=O(g)$? Well can you multiply $g(n)$ by something so its slightly above $f(n)$ always, or eventually?. These examples use $n_0 = 1$, the $n_0>n$ bit of the definition should be informally interpreted as eventual behaviour, so try and think what the functions are doing when approaching infinity

Comment: So $f(n) \leq g(n) => f(n)=\Theta(g(n)).$ If $f(n)=\Omega$ then $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$. We show that $f(n)\neq\Omega(g(n)).$ Suppose $\exists C > 0$ and $n_0$ such that $f(n) \geq g(n) * C \forall n > n_0.$ For $n>n_0$, we have $4log_9(n) > C * 5log_9(n) => 4log_9(n)/5log_9(n) > C.$ However since $3/4$ is less than $1$, the LHS will be smaller than $c$ and $n_o > n$. This is a contradiction. That sound correct?

Comment: $f(n) \leq g(n) \implies f = O(g)$ under the assumption that $g = O(f)$, However this is quite restrictive, you could have $f(n) > g(n)$ for every $n$ such that $f = O(g)$, for example $f=2x$, $g=x$. This isn't a contradiction, since if $C = \frac{1}{2}$ then $\frac{4log(n)}{5log(n)} = \frac{4}{5} > \frac{1}{2}$ is always true. Remember its there exists a $C$, not for any $C$. If you let $C = 10$ for example, then what happens?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is not too hard: $g(n) \leq f(n)$ for every $n$, so $f(n) = O(g(n))$. To prove that $g(n) \neq O(f(n))$, let $C>0$ be arbitrary. Find $n_0$ so that $(12/7)^{n_0} > C$ (how?). Then if $n \geq n_0$ then $12^n \geq C 7^n$.

For the second one, here's a hint: $\log_9(n^4)=4 \log_9(n)$, $\log_9(n^5)=5 \log_9(n)$.